# Setup a Fedora-based Kubernetes cluster knowing I'll need VMs

Tags: virtual-machine, clustering

I'm new to Kubernetes, and trying to figure out the best way to handle VMs in my particular (homelab) setup. Specifically, I need a software to handle the integration between Kubernetes and the VM layer (like [frakti](https://github.com/kubernetes/frakti) or [KubeVirt](http://www.kubevirt.io/)), help ease management while still running what I need to run. Alternatively, if you don't think an integration would be helpful, what hypervisor/management software would fit my needs?

Requirements:

- The hosts run Fedora. I'm open to alternatives, but I do prefer Fedora.
- There will be at least 1 Windows 10 VM, it needs to be as close to the metal as it can get.
- VGA Passthrough (or its equivalent) will be going for the Windows 10 VM.
- The VMs need to be able to reach databases running on Kubernetes
- I want some way of checking host usage via a single interface. I don't want to have to look at each machine individually in order to figure out how many cores/how much RAM is used by VMs.

Comment: Sure, there is value in suggesting "Don't integrate VMs with Kubernetes", but I don't need a how-to for that. Just a general outline of an architecture, and I can figure out how to make it happen. (IE, "Make your kubernetes nodes VMs" or "Run Kubernetes bare-metal on your VM Hosts" (I don't know if either of these are a good idea))

Comment: Thanks for your update! I adjusted it a little more with what I understood from your comments, and hope I got it correct – in which case it's indeed asking for software now. Reopened. Feel free to adjust again – and good luck!

Comment: Looks right to me, but I'll have to see what sort of answers roll in. Thanks for the re-open.